# a:links for a specific element apply the whole page links

Tags: css, hyperlink, element

I have an issue in my CSS/HTML5 code.
Like the title says, when i'm giving an a:link for a specific elements (divs), it changes the whole page's links to those settings (color).

Now, I've never seen this problem before.
I double check my syntex for links, but it seems to be right.
I tried deleting cache, and refresh by Shift+F5. also tried it on Edge and FireFox.

```
ul a:link, a:visited, a:active {
    color: #e20000;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:link, a:visited, a:active {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Now, I need it to stay in the limit of the elements i've set.

What may cause that issue? 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comma separates multiple selectors that have the same rule applied to them. The `ul` at the beginning of the rule is part of the 1st selector (`ul a:link`), and doesn't effect the visited and active states.

```
ul a:link, a:visited, a:active {
    color: #e20000;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Add `ul` to all of them:

```
ul a:link, ul a:visited, ul a:active {
    color: #e20000;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

The (experimental) [`:is`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:is) rule (formerly known as `:any` or `:matches`) enables to include several rules under a common denominator. Unfortunately, this feature still lacks support, and is buggy.

```
ul :is(a:link, a:visited, a:active) {
    color: #e20000;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Example:

```css
div :is(a:link, a:visited, a:active) {
  color: #e20000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/** needed for browsers' compatibility **/
div :-webkit-any(a:link, a:visited, a:active) {
  color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}

div :-moz-any(a:link, a:visited, a:active) {
  color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}

:matches(header, main, footer) p:hover {
  color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Not effected</a>

<div>
  <a href="#">Effected</a>
</div>
```